# Looping html div using php to show image from folder

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I have a folder "blah" that contains a lots of images.

I want to show all my images into my page.

Here my html code:

```
<div class="cp-thumb cp-masonry cp-thumbs616 masonry-brick">
   <img src="blah/225cd24c144611e3b69022000a1deb4b_7.jpg" class="img_235x235" />
</div>
```

When I use php for loop to show all the image, it does not work:

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
{
   echo "<div class='cp-thumb cp-masonry cp-thumbs616 masonry-brick'>
       <img src='blah/225cd24c144611e3b69022000a1deb4b_7.jpg'class='img_235x235' />
     </div>";      
}     
?>
```

Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that img src is right?

Comment: And why are you posting the same image 10 times?

Comment: I just try to loop the div but it does not loop at all. I dont know how to loop through the folder to show all image that is why i am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `GLOB` like

```
foreach(glob('blah/'.'*') as $filename){
    echo "<div class='cp-thumb cp-masonry cp-thumbs616 masonry-brick'>
              <img src='".$filename."' class='img_235x235' />
          </div>"; 
}
```

COnsidered that all the image names are different and also the directory contains only images.

In my local I have images in my `proj/blah/` So I have done like

```
<img src='proj/".$filename."' class='img_235x235' />
```

Comment: I dont knw why my images didnt come out.. =(

Comment: You are getting image names..??May be you need to add your hosting and main folder names..I have checked in my local and it was working fine

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. Just copy and paste

```
<?php

$dir = dir("blah");

while($filename=$dir->read()) {

    if($filename=="." || $filename=="..") continue;

    echo "<div class='cp-thumb cp-masonry cp-thumbs616 masonry-brick'>
       <img src='blah/".$filename."'class='img_235x235' />
     </div>";  
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `glob` function if you want to display all images on a folder.

```
foreach (glob("*") as $filename)
{
    echo '<div class="cp-thumb cp-masonry cp-thumbs616 masonry-brick">
              <img src="blah/'.$filename.'" class="img_235x235" />
          </div>';


}
```

keep in mind this function returns an array, so if you do not want to out put them all you have the ability to configure that,
please read this.

https://www.php.net/glob

Answer (score 0):

use glob to read images

```
<?php
foreach (glob("blah/*.jpg") as $filename) {
    echo "<div class='cp-thumb cp-masonry cp-thumbs616 masonry-brick'><img src='blah/". $filename . "'class='img_235x235' /></div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `directory path` of `blah folder`

Try this,

```
foreach(glob('blah/{*.gif,*.jpg,*.png}',GLOB_BRACE) as $img){// you can add more extension here
    echo "<div class='cp-thumb cp-masonry cp-thumbs616 masonry-brick'>
       <img src='blah/".$img."'class='img_235x235' />
     </div>";
}
```

Read [Glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a [jQuery solution](http://www.justinwhall.com/directory-jquery-slider/). Add an image slider that will pick up all the images directly from the folder.

Includes

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- directorySlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/directorySlider.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div id='slider-main' class='cp-thumb cp-masonry cp-thumbs616 masonry-brick'></div>
```

JS

```
$('#slider-main').directorySlider({
    animation: 'fade',
    filebase: 'slide_',
    directory: 'blah/',
    extension: 'jpg',
    numslides: 10,
    height: 200
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me just fine tysm.

```
<?php
foreach (glob("blah/*.jpg") as $filename) {
    echo "<div class='cp-thumb cp-masonry cp-thumbs616 masonry-brick'><img src='blah/". $filename . "'class='img_235x235' /></div>";
}
?>
```